# Margin: 0 auto; not working on a div the needs to inherit a width from 2 enclosed elements

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to center the flame and the heading to the middle of the white box.

HTML

```
        <div class="contentheading">
            <div class="floatmiddle">
                <img src="images/flame45x45.png">
                <h3>Receive only the email you want.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.contentheading {
       position: relative;
       height: 45px;
       margin-top: 30px;
       width: 636px;           //this is the full width of the white box//
}

.floatmiddle {
       margin: 0 auto;
       height: 45px;
       display: block;
}

.contentheading img {
       position: absolute;
}

.floatmiddle > h3 {
       font-family: "signika";
       font-size: 22px;
       font-weight: 500;
       color: #37434f;
       height: 45px;
       line-height: 45px;
       margin: 0 0 0 60px;
       text-align: center;
       vertical-align: top;
       position: absolute;
}
```

I need the .float middle to inherit the width of the two enclosing elements - the image (45 x 45px) and the text (which will be different length for each chapter i have) so i need one class/formula so i can just go through and pop in the headings and no matter the headings length the heading and the fireball will be centered within the white div.

Comment: I can make the width of .floadmiddle the same as the enclosing divs if it is set to position:absolute but then it does not float in the middle...

Comment: why all the absolute positioning?

Comment: Without it the h3, heading dropped below to a different line?? @webeno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;` to center this `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/d8gyd9gu/

HTML

```
<div class="contentheading">
    <div class="floatmiddle">
        <img src="http://www.neatimage.com/im/lin_logo.gif" alt="">
        <h3>Receive only the email you want.</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.contentheading {
       height: 45px;
       margin-top: 30px;
       width: 636px;
       text-align: center;
}


.floatmiddle {
       height: 45px;
       display: inline-block;
}

.contentheading img {
       float: left;
        margin: 20px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.floatmiddle > h3 {
       font-family: "signika";
       font-size: 22px;
       font-weight: 500;
       color: #37434f;
       height: 45px;
       line-height: 45px;
       padding: 0px 0px 0px 60px;
}
```

Comment: My page is all over the place now haha might have to tidy a few things up before i try this again, i can see that the heading is centered tho! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use flexbox you can do it really simply like this:

```css
.contentheading {
  border: 1px dashed #ff0000;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 636px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contentheading h3 {
  font-family: "signika";
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #37434f;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentheading">
  <img src="images/flame45x45.png" width="45" height="45" />
  <h3>Receive only the email you want.</h3>
</div>
```

If you need to support older browsers make sure you add the prefixed versions.

Comment: I cannot use flexbox unfortunately! Would be ideal though!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely pare your markup and styling down. If you only need to center the text and the image in a div of a fixed width, you can simply use `text-align: center` on the parent container, and `display: inline-block` on the two elements within. The following markup and styling is about as little as you need:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-heading">
  <img src="images/flame45x45.png">
  <h3>Receive only the email you want.</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-heading {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto; /** Centers on the page **/
  text-align: center;
  width: 636px;
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 45px; /** Only really works if you can rely on only displaying one line of text **/
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /** Need this to keep inline-block elements from staggering **/
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  background-color: black; /** Purely so we can see this **/
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
}
```

That's really all you need.

[Codepen sketch](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gDpmq)